# NaN when using constrained minimization in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, maximize

I am trying to maximize a function of 10 variables. I do this by the following piece of code:

```
b    = [1 2 3 4 1 7 -1 -4 9 1].';     %// initial value of the decision variable
goal = @(b) -sum(F(b));
```

Because I want to maximize `F` for a given set of parameters `b`, of which the last value should be ≥ 0. I implemented the optimization as follows:

```
%// lower bounds for decision variable
lb = [-inf(1,9) 0];

%// upper bounds for decision variable
ub = inf(1,10);

myfminoptions = optimset('Display','Iter', 'Algorithm','active-set');
theta1 = fmincon(goal, theta0, [],[],[],[], lb,ub, [], myfminoptions);
```

That is, I find the minimum of the negative of the function, which should be the same as finding the maximum of that function.

My problem is, that for every iteration I get that the first-order optimality is `Inf` and thus `'Hessian not updated'`.

Additionally the value of my function `NaN` in the first iteration, which I simply don't understand. This might be the cause, but I not sure.

**Edit**

This is the function that I am using:

```
function ll = mytobit(theta); 
global x y; 
b=theta(1:size(theta,1)-1); 
s=theta(size(theta,1)); 
ll = (y==0).*log(1-normcdf(x*b/s))+ (y>0).*(-0.5*(log(2*pi)+log(s^2)+(y-x*b).^2/s^2)); 
return;
```

When calling the function for the theta0, I get N likelihood values (N is the number of rows in X and Y) which I am supposed to.

An example of Y and X:

```
    Y = [0;0;2047;1890;1975]

    X = [2300, 34, 1156, 0, 1;
         2100, 35, 1225, 0, 1;
         2760, 36, 1296, 1, 0;
         2300, 37, 1369, 1, 0
         2455, 38, 1444, 0, 0]
```

Comment: What is `function(b)`? Is `theta0 == b`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. theta0 = B. The function is a likelihood function for a tobit model, which takes in some independent variables (x) variables and some dependent variables (y). The function then returns some likelihood values for each individual in the dataset.

Comment: Can you paste a toy version of that function? I'd like to be able to reproduce your error...In principle there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, so I suspect the problem lies in that function.

Comment: function ll = mytobit(theta); global x y;

b=theta(1:size(theta,1)-1);

s=theta(size(theta,1));

ll = (y==0).*log(1-normcdf(x*b/s))+ (y>0).*(-0.5*(log(2*pi)+log(s^2)+(y-x*b).^2/s^2));


return; Sorry, I'm unable to write it more lucidly. The ; is just a new line. When calling the function for the theta0, I get N likelihood values (N is the number of rows in X and Y) which I am supposed to. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @user2329754 It is recommended to include this kind of additional information in the question. This time I have already edited it for you.

Comment: OK...Can you give examples of `x` and `y`? :)

Comment: Yeah, sure. Sorry I have not. It is edited in the original question above.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the 'sqp' algorithm, as opposed to active-set. The sqp algorithm can recover from NaNs produced when s strays to close to zero, where the derivatives are undefined.

Also, you would hopefully not be initializing the s variable near zero in theta0.

Because s is actually supposed to be strictly greater than zero, it may help to re-express it as  s=exp(-d/2) where d is a new unconstrained unknown variable. Also, your objective function only depends on b through the quantity B=b/s. So, you could formulate this way

```
ll = (y==0).*log(1-normcdf(x*B))+ (y>0).*(-0.5*(log(2*pi)-d+(y*exp(-d/2)-x*B).^2));
```

Now there are no ill-defined regions in the function or its derivatives.